# In the array of n elements, first n-(root)n elements are sorted, we have to sort the array

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, sorting

We have given an array of n integers of which first n-(squareroot)n elements are sorted (it means (root)n elements from the last are not sorted). We have to sort the entire array with minimum time complexity. What can be the complexity? And what would be our approach? When I tried to solve it, my complexity is O(n) by first sort the remaining array and merge it. Is there any algorithm to solve it with less than O(n)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your "array" is actually a [skip-list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list), it can be done in `O(log(n)sqrt(n))`

```
for each element x in reminder:
   remove x from skip list   (O(1))
   find first element smaller then x in sorted part   (O(logn))
   insert x to the found position    (O(1))
```

complexity will be `sqrt(n)*log(n)`

Note that if the data is an actual array, you will need to shift all elements to the right for a single change (if one of the elements in the reminder is the smallest, for example) - and this is done alone in `O(n)`, so for an array you cannot go better then `O(n)`

Comment: I have always loved your "Algorithms" answers and also the speed at which you think. You are definitely the best guy out there for Algorithms in Stack Overflow.

Comment: I just want to point out that building a skip list for `n` elements has expected complexity `O(nlogn)` and also that removing an element from the skip list takes `O(logn)` on average.

Comment: @pkacprzak (1) The answer for skip list assumes a skip list is already existing, if it is not - this is useless, so I agree with this comment. (2) No. Removing an element from a skip list is O(logn) worst case and O(1) on average. for each node you have probability of 1/2 to have a "link up" this gives us `E(nodes removed in del) = Sum(1/2^i | i =0,...,lgn) < 2`. If you are refering to the fact that the element should be first 'found' before deletion, note that this is iterating, so you already have the pointer to the element.

Comment: @amit You're right, if you delete those nodes from the bottom using pointers then deletion is `O(1)` on average